# How to set state value from custom init in SwiftUI

Tags: state, swiftui

I tried to make a color picker that has a custom init function to set the original color. And 3 state variable (hue, saturation, brightness) to hold value that will be changed by smaller components. After trying many ways, I still cannot change value of 3 @State variables in custom init function. So weir. Can anyone help me? Thanks

```swift
struct ColorPicker: View {

    @State var saturation: CGFloat = 0.5
    @State var brightness: CGFloat = 0.5
    @State var hue: CGFloat = 0.5
    @State var alpha: CGFloat = 1

    var oriColor : UIColor? = nil
    var oriHue: CGFloat = 0
    var oriSaturation: CGFloat = 0
    var oriBrightness: CGFloat = 0

    init(oriColor:UIColor?) {
        self.oriColor = oriColor

        if let color = oriColor{

            color.getHue(&oriHue, saturation: &oriSaturation, brightness: &oriBrightness, alpha: &alpha)

            self._hue = State(initialValue:oriHue)
            self._saturation = State(initialValue:oriSaturation)
            self._brightness = State(initialValue:oriBrightness)

            self.hue = oriHue

            debugPrint("set value:\(hue)")
        }
    }

    var body: some View {

        debugPrint("make view with:\(self.hue)")
        let bindingSaturation = Binding<CGFloat>(get: {return self.saturation}, set: {val in self.saturation = val})
        let bindingBrightness = Binding<CGFloat>(get: {return self.brightness}, set: {val in self.brightness = val})
        let bindingHue = Binding<CGFloat>(get: {return self.hue}, set: {val in self.hue = val})

        debugPrint("make view with:\(self.hue)")
        return Text("debugging")
    }
}
```

[Click here to view code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOguX.png)

--- UPDATE apply answer from Procrastin8

I changed my code as your suggest

```swift
struct ColorPicker: View {

    @State var hue: CGFloat

    var oriHue: CGFloat = 0.5
    var oriSaturation: CGFloat = 0.5
    var oriBrightness: CGFloat = 0.5
    var oriAlpha: CGFloat = 1

    init(oriColor:UIColor?) {

        if let color = oriColor {
            color.getHue(&oriHue, saturation: &oriSaturation, brightness: &oriBrightness, alpha: &oriAlpha)
            self.hue = oriHue
        }
        else {
            self._hue = State(initialValue:oriHue)
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        debugPrint("make view with:\(self.hue)")
        return VStack {
            BrightnessGrid.init(hue: self.$hue)
        }
    }
}

struct BrightnessGrid : View {
    @Binding var hue: CGFloat

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("hue:\(self.hue)")
        }
    }
}
```

But got "'self' used before all stored properties are initialized" error, as you can see in attach image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXwfC.png)

I guest the reason is when we have custom init, then the default initializer will not work then we must manual set the value for @State variable by ourself. Then it's back to the first case.

The init function now is

```swift
init(oriColor:UIColor?) {

        if let color = oriColor {
            color.getHue(&oriHue, saturation: &oriSaturation, brightness: &oriBrightness, alpha: &oriAlpha)
        }
        self._hue = State(initialValue:oriHue)
    }
```

and still not work.

--- UPDATE 2 
I make a new test project and apply the answer of User3441734. When apply in main view it's work perfectly. Then I separated to module it like this.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var colorA: UIColor = UIColor.orange
    var colorB: UIColor = UIColor.blue
    @State var oriColor: UIColor? = nil

    func changeToColorA(){
        oriColor = colorA
    }

    func changeToColorB(){
        oriColor = colorB
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Button(action:changeToColorA){
                    Text("Color A")
                }
                Button(action:changeToColorB){
                    Text("Color B")
                }
            }
            TestView(oriColor: oriColor)
        }
    }
}
struct TestView: View {

    @State var hue: CGFloat

    var oriHue: CGFloat = 0.5
    var oriSaturation: CGFloat = 0.5
    var oriBrightness: CGFloat = 0.5
    var oriAlpha: CGFloat = 1

    init(oriColor:UIColor?) {

        if let color = oriColor {
            color.getHue(&oriHue, saturation: &oriSaturation, brightness: &oriBrightness, alpha: &oriAlpha)
        }
        _hue = State(initialValue: oriHue)
    }

    var body: some View {
        debugPrint("make view with:\(self.hue)")
        return VStack {
            Text("\(hue)").background(Color(hue: Double(hue), saturation: Double(oriSaturation), brightness: Double(oriBrightness), opacity: Double(oriAlpha)))

            .onTapGesture {
                self.hue = 0.22
            }
            Slider(value: $hue, in: 0 ... 1) {
                Text("HUE")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then nothing happen when clicking on buttons Color A, Color B. Did I do some thing wrong?

Comment: it would be much easier for us, who want to help, if you copy reproducable and copyable code in here instead of letting out code for BrightnessGrid and HueSlider. Or Change/simplify your code in that way, we can copy and run it, if you dont want to show your code here...

Answer (score 3):

You are setting up default initial values then attempting to overwrite the `State` container in your `init` function. Try setting them up at the same time, either with your calculated values or your defaults, but all in the `init` function.

```swift
struct ColorPicker: View {

    @State var saturation: CGFloat
    @State var brightness: CGFloat
    @State var hue: CGFloat
    @State var alpha: CGFloat

    init(_ color: UIColor?) {
      if let color = color {
          // what you had before
      } else {
          self._saturation = State(initialValue: 0.5)
          // etc.
      }
    }
```

I also wouldn't entirely rely on calculated values inside your `body` function. Try just having a label that prints out those values instead and see what you get, as opposed to your debug printing.

Note: You know that `@State` vends a `Binding` as its `projectedValue` right?

```swift
SomeView(colorComponent: "hue", binding: $hue)
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. I have had applied your solution but still no luck. You can see in the updated section. I hope that i dont mis your idea.

Comment: Your screenshot shows something completely different. You removed `@State` from your instance variable declarations and you're still setting default values.

Comment: Did you watch the screenshot from the head of original post? I updated the new apply follow your suggest in the second part with UPDATE label. I simply use 1 State variable named hue, and if we dont set value for this state variable the compiler will complain.

Comment: Yeah I saw. And like i said, you're doing 2 completely different things in your `init` function. `self.hue` is NOT the same thing as `self._hue`. In one, you're setting the _wrapped_ value and in the other you're setting the entire `State` variable.

Answer (score 1):

to change initial value of State use its underlying value

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var hue: CGFloat

    var oriHue: CGFloat = 0.5
    var oriSaturation: CGFloat = 0.5
    var oriBrightness: CGFloat = 0.5
    var oriAlpha: CGFloat = 1

    init(oriColor:UIColor?) {

        if let color = oriColor {
            color.getHue(&oriHue, saturation: &oriSaturation, brightness: &oriBrightness, alpha: &oriAlpha)
        }
        _hue = State(initialValue: oriHue)
    }

    var body: some View {
        debugPrint("make view with:\(self.hue)")
        return VStack {
            Text("\(hue)").background(Color(hue: Double(hue), saturation: Double(oriSaturation), brightness: Double(oriBrightness), opacity: Double(oriAlpha)))

            .onTapGesture {
                self.hue = 0.22
            }
            Slider(value: $hue, in: 0 ... 1) {
                Text("HUE")
            }
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView(oriColor: UIColor.orange))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but I do exactly same as your.

Comment: So what doesn't work? This way the txt1 initial value is changed from init, as you requested.

Comment: I have had created new project and test your code and it worked. Maybe the problem is somewhere else than init function, because I used exactly same at your. Thank.

Comment: @user13441734 . your code work well. For more convenient I split to separated module like UPDATE 2 But It didnot work as expect. Can you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

After trying many ways but not success. I use this code that can work.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var oriColor: UIColor? = nil
    @State var hue: CGFloat = 1
    @State var saturation: CGFloat = 1
    @State var brightness: CGFloat = 1
    @State var alpha: CGFloat = 1

    func setColor(_ oriColor: UIColor){
        self.oriColor = oriColor
        oriColor.getHue(&self.hue, saturation: &self.saturation, brightness: &self.brightness, alpha: &self.alpha)
    }
    func changeToColorA(){
        setColor(UIColor.orange)
    }
    func changeToColorB(){
        setColor(UIColor.blue)
    }
    var body: some View {

         VStack {
            HStack {
                Button(action:changeToColorA) {
                    Text("Color A")
                }

                Button(action:changeToColorB) {
                    Text("Color B")
                }
            }

            ColorPicker(hue: self.$hue, saturation: self.$saturation, brightness: self.$brightness, alpha: self.$alpha)
        }
    }
}

struct ColorPicker: View {

    @Binding var hue: CGFloat
    @Binding var saturation: CGFloat
    @Binding var brightness: CGFloat
    @Binding var alpha: CGFloat

    var body: some View {

         return VStack {
            TestView.init(hue: self.$hue, saturation: self.$saturation, brightness: self.$brightness, alpha:self.$alpha )
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View {

    @Binding var hue: CGFloat
    @Binding var saturation: CGFloat
    @Binding var brightness: CGFloat
    @Binding var alpha: CGFloat

    var body: some View {

        debugPrint("make view with:\(self.hue)")

        return VStack {
            Text("\(hue)").background(Color(hue: Double(hue), saturation: Double(saturation), brightness: Double(brightness), opacity: Double(alpha)))


            Slider(value: $hue, in: 0 ... 1) {
                Text("HUE")
            }
        }
    }
}
```